# Hose repair using a clamp

Tags: repair, hose

I replaced a damaged hose's end with the brass and chrome-plated clamp you see in the figure.

[image: hose repair]

Since I wasn't able to get a direct grip with the clamp, I added a second layer of the hose, pictured.

I have two problems with this solution:

1. It leaks.
2. The sharp end of the chrome part is just waiting to cut someone's skin.

I could experiment with layers of teflon between the hose and the brass to stop the leak, but I can't think of a reasonable solution for the exposed sharp clamp right where the hose would be held.

What else should I be doing?

Comment: If all the parts are sized correctly this is very easy. You've purchased the wrong size.

Comment: @Tyson Both are 5/8", and they fit fairly snug.

Comment: The stainless steel clamp?  I'm just about to go water with a hose that has exactly that repair.  It's really straightforward.

Comment: @Tyson My palms might handle the exposed sharp metal just fine, but for those with softer skin on the bottom of their feet (i.e. kids), it's a disaster waiting to happen. The bracket really should be wrapped somehow, hopefully by a method that neither disintegrates quickly (such as duct tape) nor becomes a magnet for mold/rot (such as wrapping a piece of cloth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to crank down on the hose clamp. If the size of the repair fitting is two small it will take some tape to build up the barbed part that goes inside the pipe. I have used electrical tape to do this in the past, Teflon might work but not as well as a vinyl that is thicker, I like the hose clamp style they don't strip out as easy but then I wrap the end with electrical tape,,, you guessed it I am an electrician. We have many hoses at our farm with tractors and horses stepping cutting hoses we have lots of repairs and this has worked well for me.

Comment: Patience turned out to be what's needed. Crank down, wait a day or two, then tighten again. What is happening, possibly, is that the plastic (rubber?) takes time to mold to the grooves, and then one can tighten again to create a watertight seal.